# Pandas DataFrame grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe that looks like the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6TmR.png)

The dataframe counts the number of question according to their state:

```
question_count_data.columns = ['date', 'curriculum_name_en', 'concept', 'language', 
                               'concept_name_en', 'concept_name_tc', 'state', 'question_count']


question_count_data['state'] = question_count_data['state']\
    .map({10: 'DRAFT', 20: 'REVIEW', 30: 'PUBLISHED', 40: 'ERROR', 50: 'DISABLED'})
```

I have used the following method to create this dataframe:

```
question_count_data = df_question.groupby(['date', 'concept__curriculum__name_en', 'concept', 
                                           'language', 'concept_name_en', 'concept_name_tc', 'state', ],
                                            as_index=False)['question_count'].sum()
```

I want to now create separate columns for each state DRAFT, REVIEW, PUBLISHED, etc and provide the question count in rows , that has to look like the following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbgmI.png)

Whats the best possible way to do this using my question_count_data Dataframe? I dont want to change the groupby method already implemented because thats what providing me the question count.

I do not think having another groupby method would be possible solution because what i ultimately want to do is getting the row value of the column State and getting them to separate columns like Draft, Review, Published, etc and then provide the count for each date.

A detailed explanation would be helpful please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are really close, need to remove `as_index=False` for `Series` with `MultiIndex` and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
cols = ['date', 'concept__curriculum__name_en', 'concept', 
        'language', 'concept_name_en', 'concept_name_tc', 'state']
question_count_data = (df_question.groupby(cols)['question_count']
                                  .sum()
                                  .unstack(fill_value=0))
```